# Trouble with playing .wav files from JAR

Tags: java, audio, jar, export, wav

I'm having some strange trouble with playing a WAV file from a JAR.
First, I can simply read it using ClassLoader when working in Eclipse. Everything works fine there.
Then I export my project to a JAR file. But now it says that no such files exists although I can see it with an archivator; for non-WAV files it works fine.
When I decided to export it to an external directory first the WAV file exports corrupted (while other files are not damaged, again).
What should be my problem then? I've made a research, but I couldn't find anything related to any trouble with WAV files or heavy files.
How do I do it correctly and why does it work for small files but not the big ones (or sound files)?

Thank you for your awnsers.

EDIT:
The package explorer in Eclipse:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtCOd.png
The code used to actually get the file:
`private static MusicPlayer music = new MusicPlayer(new InputStream[]{MusicPlayer.class.getResourceAsStream("default/Final.wav")}, new InputStream[]{});`
Finally, the exception:
`java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at ru.windcorp.game.music.Music.run(Music.java:31)
        at ru.windcorp.game.music.MusicPlayer.playMenu(MusicPlayer.java:29)
        at ru.windcorp.game.GameMain.main(GameMain.java:152)`

Comment: We really need to see the code in question as well as (ideally) your directory/jar structure to determine what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your AudioInputStream from an InputStream. Make it from a URL.

(1) URL's can "see" into jars.

(2) getAudioInputStream(InputStream inputStream) likely runs a Markability or Resetability test (or both) on the audio file when it is converted to an InputStream. Most audio files seem to fail at this stage.

(3) getAudioInputStream(URL url) does NOT run a Markability test on the audio, thus circumventing the issue.

Check out the API for the different input parameters of this method, for the AudioSystem object.

*Whoa! Why are you using com.sun.media.sound code? I think that has mostly been deprecated, hasn't it? SoftMidiAudioFileReader is no where to be found in the Java 7 SE API. A slew of people are using this and generating errors. Where did you get the suggestion to use this?*

Comment: I personally avoid using deprecated API, and I didn't mention any com.sun .media.sound stuff. I was literaly surprised when I saw this code. I'm using Java 8 to run but... Yeah, this code uses Java 7 libs (just for me to be sure that program will run on computers with outdated JVM).

Comment: Re "I didn't mention..." Your error message references a call to the com.sun.media.sound library. That's why I brought it up. I think if you stick with javax.audio.sampled API you will be okay. It has been reasonably stable and would work with Java 7 or 8, maybe even 6. Again, I'm curious where you came across the MusicPlayer object. Did you write it yourself? Cut/paste from elsewhere? I'm not trying to be critical about attempting to use this code, just curious!

Comment: MusicPlayer is my own creation and it calls some tech classes, after which this code is finally used to start the music: `@Override
 public void run() {
  try {
   Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
   AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
   clip.open(inputStream);
   clip.start(); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Did you ever get this working? Looking at my answer, I might not have been clear. I was suggesting using URL not File as your form of addressing, and making the AudioInputStream from the URL, thus avoiding the Mark/Reset support testing that can arise when an InputStreams is used as the input parameter.